# Is it possible to create a map without hardcoding the class name `Map`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I tried to write a utility function which returns an object that is the same as its argument. The function works fine for most classes, except for ES6 collection types such as Map:

```
function createInstanceOfSameClass(arg) {
    return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(arg));
}

const m1 = new Map();
const m2 = createInstanceOfSameClass(m1);
m2.set(1, "x"); //  Uncaught TypeError: Method Map.prototype.set called on incompatible receiver #<Map>
```

[The jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/Yaojian/nogv1Lmw/).

Comment: `eval("var obj = new " + className);`

Comment: @RyanMcCullagh No. Not all classes have a name (that you can access), and they might not be in scope or not even be unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... You can get the constructor this way:

```
function create(obj){
    return new obj.constructor();
}
```

Comment: Or, skip the wrapper entirely and just call `new obj.constructor();` directly. I guess it depends on how often you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createInstanceOfSameClass(arg) {
  if(arg.has){
     return new Map();
  }
  if(Array.isArray(arg)){
    return [];
   }
    return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(arg));
}
```

Simply detect if its a map/Array...
http://jsbin.com/yimatuquce/edit?console

Comment: What if it is a `Set`?